# Python + facebook Prophet error in forecasting

Tags: python, forecasting, facebook-prophet

Tell me what I'm doing wrong. I insert a time series into the prophet input, I get a forecast, but it looks like a repeating pattern. And absolutely nothing like the forecast.

[image: result of forecasting]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sktime.forecasting.fbprophet import Prophet

salesData = [-22.899810546632665, -9.11228684600458, -2.0232803049199948, 2.769880807257286, 0.8771850621655833, 5.240523426843543, -4.101202313494994, -7.438606008637052, 1.8640765345461658, 2.6530910373074446, 0.6816397761862772, -5.369005299189235, 2.2995963745863106, -0.9488515556078191, -2.490658867190924, 1.495849663486175, 1.849161620028351, 4.574290696478775, 1.8606830281445728, 4.5401410593181915, -5.0697333665656465, -6.8037280937002205, -0.41728360333518366, -0.397468128796101, 1.0964987155515669, 0.9241856998562122, 7.4987636157925674, -0.9036386621033988, -4.168575486734736, 1.0455838313276498, 3.5501944037387263, 3.7117838928135645, -2.249350543191892, -0.9325974026874418, -7.311336798694246, -4.769395107147262, 1.7712018973129169, 2.6453558795159933, 4.805405561414102, 3.8260210836580826, 4.394563377865766, -7.139777583888209, -5.2122838464550005, 3.4707574766029285, 2.123455819765237, -1.9216781708796522, -2.696474264481818, 4.3072928655137765, -4.835464310939693, -4.715567254042179, 4.837730825402849, 7.923534727836371, 2.584596049852443, -3.485498284318281, -0.1855356912460123, -6.521909243801553, -5.939170879395363, 1.6440237896855472, 3.580429853920485, 1.3774941555516405, -0.9196574985857207, 3.992221788802156, -1.935957074886787, -3.7997988733436756, 2.714021017101176, 3.0294525494024, -0.3930365150839221, -5.009292419867927, 0.7546979885019088, -2.1174967380732563, -4.788564073800437, -0.952874211429072, 2.781963488012231, 7.9459681649254525, 3.629590909086231, 1.7861643533664724, -4.624868314831825, -3.520074030081029, 0.6087172369876066, -1.1062737995516618, 2.6359835833191347, 3.3113477448178408, 1.689695851822031, -7.095504239394035, -3.5249810225744573, 6.588101250291994, 4.085385013734247, 1.4832832692866167, 0.9734299151513489, 2.6112162346070504, -4.9010306775769275, -4.901239447552297, 3.8950095820646213, 1.3406292538018294, -0.5282837546993199, 0.753952323998906, 5.169079271848939, -1.6201860123291287, -3.762162418130858, 4.275051800352548, 1.1232101108209884, -2.346202168861502, -2.2826782569255832, 4.505890767755019, -1.8190665385734426, -7.658329819004368, 0.10987851344719599, 2.261897124488089, 1.5392501079425294, -1.5844040229997323, 3.683259856560565, 1.1829387289652118, -4.237938986869985, -1.8026666795474242, -1.7946250217271775, 1.2933788146545167, -1.0374578898470987, 0.3434342927014619, -1.7379029412348141, -2.7776369281015727, 1.6505959323578854, -0.9845160970786264, 2.73600663050934, 1.912088176390693, 1.5064291044360094, -4.185993981551647, -5.078603135175087, 1.580810068159558, -1.827676946096123, 1.630245976939615, 0.8767970006001486, 1.9191902082102914, -4.255257065345466, -2.2920106230775206, 6.452410589766132, 1.490241277720836, 0.29745142343220105, -2.022758354575668, 1.166445503203743, -5.432583501507066, -3.2137062880925975, 5.964950921188283, 2.647583725388037, -0.5602763181540208, -2.4389785201658296, 4.185419628541755, -0.47753222108873544, -1.7125950465824034, 2.7545209513686912, 0.342690874987082, -1.1297987908423226, -2.044073816608947, 3.2448098431419643, -1.3658253244506777, -3.0147128514534787, 1.4737794066696859, 2.1205697423773944, 3.048455865920152, 1.3545170452380675, 2.10067165714669, -3.793222879838366, -4.987808008915057, 0.5774951459683085, 1.8218849657934184, 3.307490703034141, 1.9780212087919815, 1.017752319426859, -3.987452442233335, -3.233130377966213, 3.114846702211204, 1.700873563247121, 1.4460065798295234, 1.2663580286331433, 0.587237520548546, -5.66622533912726, -6.23057647388975, 2.149189925604655, 2.414391072519844, 2.2696711137534034, 2.1172763760340816, 1.9510409807356304, -3.7813490807218475, -5.93040981385517, 1.4416758657765874, 1.2545519774333878, 1.9386196629746348, 1.2256240869780195, 0.43855005180747997, -3.8095930731545153, -4.143332375838307, 3.7552822457456716, 1.3420669360588162, 1.3597044716717293, 1.33624713051985, 2.379028078399799, -2.399594563350425, -4.541685080886469, 1.4735219894517995, -1.4039630434543284, 0.66682849702559, 2.245620397491483, 4.4033376300176785, -1.0964722703121415, -4.076951580495554, 1.291026487846525, -1.0855622042189113, 2.021799003901511, 3.3846547403984886, 3.6166899070710716, -4.452017017323524, -5.947523546504931, 2.727763154202456, 1.5435457414281373, 1.9410359497085359, 1.1448645515499383, 2.511180115230774, -3.4770991100961717, -4.9485301299371995, 2.936927151150847, 1.2839461841529514, -0.07087615474581482, -2.8211352474973266, -0.22166213045039357, -1.6727202982802507, -2.4620856585437685, 2.9576801111982873, -1.0473392914946011, 0.18190414813076905, -1.2105705320239823, 0.9254667533052756, -1.9219262740652698, -3.1279930246559458, 1.895358870235939, -2.3953798117147485, 0.6985464824740497, -0.7965075353915932, 1.9591944951226141, -2.517142588893044, -1.676673849478618, 2.84604398527469, -1.0894803442635672, 1.4783835295440593, -0.0555177047161724, 1.6056866092191024, -4.77750003577151, -1.544584491913734, 3.107665546950072, -0.006254614425190333, 0.22423083652751807, 1.7005777930167314, 4.063346193604185, -3.6485240780514268, -2.3458028072183454, 2.520911245490198, 1.9419752563460058, 0.3787820835300505, 2.0498064393412077, 3.147056229388338, -4.013310003373203, -4.362542880984366, 1.5791861684970858, 4.335046506280617, 3.024238669831118, 2.6683220831269496, 0.31176370249733526, -5.618366178783114, -5.267583273223407, 1.7326529550861156, 4.382096829624017, 2.0455805167051846, 1.0366320874674322, -1.9173315713803762, -4.0357688468957615, -2.8014441825258554, 2.565601196897678, 2.2515635294504164, 0.38499715498107095, 2.2908723588858173, -0.8979113432652993, -2.4615590649006482, -4.036513305578183, 1.1582182715691045, -0.8529716577272682, 1.0479873029226106, 6.53669448953843, 2.0355434398513306, -2.617144384775319, -8.06489443517519, 1.3207354479678062, -0.8506484224720485, 3.5640871478901244, 4.775311871095769, 1.147305365017473, -4.285285935325304, -7.629241354464176, 4.545770169990173, -0.027498715864489598, 4.46282927184866, 1.4592336747437304, 3.3706422928017794, -3.3689345604601484, -4.565641812297128, 3.1252066027077245, -2.4158556661884467, 2.37788801634457, 1.1416295182577751, 7.36482011925607, -2.76449323711107, -4.7092182478193525, -1.07666105787791, -1.0243511859113654, 4.565943078068873, 2.2147757486814985, 3.865577422352626, -7.230372724333538, -3.8398148291606216, 0.9939239884760955, 1.4333479713928579, 2.5779115150194096, 0.8221690914339992, 2.4098682578136152, -6.629744793568462, -1.5110744533130211, 2.156484249766369, 1.523300217711056, -1.1811913084632777, 0.4090603117126238, 3.3805594527547562, -4.322160577084377, -1.9905151201929976, -0.870049065627476, 1.5971712874405182, -0.28835577991007966, 3.543064453803165, 2.4565420116791223, -6.427468387594416, -5.704961705197211, -2.3371090366067686, 3.566469474778068, 1.9648586802921713, 6.430843208262392, -2.0029942672566983, -8.421587742473228, -6.414213371184237, 2.6665441248117823, 7.065714062786268, 1.4156562691223726, 3.688760151381901, -6.627341388200704, -3.2205813402830885, -1.8073613922283878, 5.3895839529841405, -1.2095943247915644, -1.1067957899354275, 7.444579017378822, 1.610983987241812, -0.5864043533909686, -6.676970411917687, 2.521362831867282, -5.1450562775781705, 5.7475117965483085, 8.371715838155241, 1.9229179356836248, -7.628853886388433]

#convert data to prophet format input
salesData = [np.float64(item) for item in salesData]
test_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
#generating dates list
listOfDates = pd.date_range(test_date, periods=364)
#compile series for Prophet input
ddf = pd.Series(salesData,index=listOfDates[:365])

#Prophet begin
forecaster = Prophet(seasonality_mode='multiplicative',
                     weekly_seasonality=True
                     )
forecaster.fit(ddf)
y_pred = forecaster.predict(fh=range(0,50))
plt.plot(range(0,144),salesData[:144], label='Original')
plt.plot(range(144,194),y_pred, label='Prophet forecast')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Before I give you the long answer. Set the `seasonality_mode` to additive. Your data is not multiplicative. Did it help?

Comment: 'forecaster = Prophet(seasonality_mode='additive',
                     n_changepoints=int(len(ddf) / 7),
                     )'

Comment: You must use the same code you showed us. `forecaster = Prophet(seasonality_mode='additive', weekly_seasonality=True)`. Did it change the forecast output?

Comment: Oh sorry. I tried your version. No effect

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Andrey to Stackoverflow. I'll give you a bit detailed answer.

1. Your time series data does not look preprocessed for the forecasting task. Why do you set the data manually? Try to clean it up a bit and have an extra look at the first datapoints is an anomaly starting from -22. Try to normalize or rescale the data.
2. Prophet is not a forecasting model you want to use, for several reasons. But the non-theoretical short answer is: Prophet is bad if you don't know the underlying mechanism of it. Try ARIMA models instead like AR, ARMA, ARIMA, SARIMA or ETS first.
3. Your setting is `multiplicative` but your time series doesn't show a multiplicative pattern. I would say it is additive since it does not increase over time. But also that you don't seem to know anything about the seasonality. It looks like a random noisy time series to me. Run it without any seasonality.

In the end. No model will help you if the data is not suitable.

**EDIT**: Adding to your approach without assuming any train/test split.

- Normalizing
- Training an ARIMA(1,0,1) and SARIMA(1,0,1)(1,0,1) s=7

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tslist = [8.5, 28.0, 29.0, 40.0, 38.5, 43.0, 31.5, 29.0, 41.0, 35.5, 39.5, 31.5, 41.5, 30.0, 30.5, 36.0, 39.5, 44.0, 37.5, 42.5, 30.0, 31.0, 41.0, 38.0, 40.5, 35.0, 41.5, 36.0, 36.5, 35.0, 44.0, 42.5, 40.0, 32.5, 26.5, 30.0, 34.5, 42.5, 40.5, 43.5, 39.5, 31.0, 30.0, 38.5, 40.0, 39.0, 33.0, 44.0, 29.0, 32.0, 35.0, 46.0, 31.5, 30.5, 32.5, 29.0, 29.5, 35.5, 39.5, 40.5, 35.5, 36.5, 28.0, 28.5, 38.5, 36.5, 26.5, 25.5, 31.5, 30.0, 30.0, 35.0, 39.0, 51.5, 38.0, 42.5, 29.5, 28.0, 41.0, 35.0, 35.0, 39.5, 37.5, 24.5, 31.0, 41.0, 38.5, 28.0, 36.0, 40.5, 31.5, 30.0, 42.5, 36.0, 32.5, 37.5, 36.0, 30.0, 30.0, 36.5, 28.0, 31.0, 26.5, 38.5, 29.13, 15.5, 29.0, 38.5, 30.0, 30.0, 35.5, 31.5, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 29.0, 30.0, 30.0, 29.5, 30.0, 30.0, 36.0, 36.0, 31.5, 30.0, 24.0, 30.0, 27.0, 34.0, 31.0, 32.0, 29.0, 31.0, 37.5, 34.5, 34.5, 25.0, 35.0, 22.0, 26.0, 37.5, 34.0, 25.0, 25.0, 34.0, 31.0, 31.0, 35.5, 27.0, 29.0, 27.5, 34.0, 30.0, 28.0, 28.5, 30.0, 36.0, 31.0, 35.0, 27.5, 26.5, 33.5, 31.0, 37.0, 36.0, 28.0, 29.0, 30.0, 29.0, 30.5, 29.0, 30.0, 29.0, 25.0, 17.0, 30.0, 35.0, 30.5, 30.0, 30.0, 24.0, 21.5, 31.0, 26.0, 27.0, 32.0, 30.0, 25.0, 21.0, 33.5, 30.0, 29.5, 30.5, 29.0, 21.5, 24.0, 28.5, 23.0, 31.0, 32.5, 30.0, 29.5, 24.0, 30.0, 30.0, 29.0, 30.0, 34.0, 23.0, 24.5, 34.0, 29.0, 30.5, 27.5, 30.5, 23.0, 25.0, 29.5, 31.5, 29.0, 19.0, 25.5, 27.5, 23.5, 32.0, 21.5, 28.5, 27.5, 19.5, 27.0, 22.0, 31.0, 24.5, 31.5, 25.0, 32.0, 28.0, 30.0, 30.0, 27.0, 32.0, 28.5, 32.0, 26.5, 27.5, 30.0, 29.5, 30.0, 33.5, 37.0, 29.5, 29.0, 35.5, 36.0, 30.5, 35.5, 35.0, 28.5, 32.0, 34.0, 37.0, 31.0, 33.0, 34.5, 25.5, 28.0, 34.0, 36.0, 36.0, 36.0, 28.54, 22.5, 26.5, 37.0, 35.0, 35.5, 37.0, 35.5, 31.5, 31.5, 36.5, 36.0, 32.0, 51.33, 36.5, 32.0, 30.0, 36.0, 36.5, 37.0, 41.5, 34.5, 29.5, 28.0, 40.0, 39.5, 44.5, 35.5, 45.0, 29.5, 35.5, 41.5, 32.5, 34.5, 37.0, 51.5, 32.5, 27.0, 25.5, 40.5, 43.5, 37.5, 40.5, 28.0, 34.0, 41.5, 38.0, 38.5, 33.0, 41.0, 30.0, 33.5, 43.0, 40.5, 39.5, 42.5, 40.0, 30.5, 32.0, 33.0, 41.5, 34.5, 32.0, 42.0, 27.5, 24.0, 35.5, 34.5, 36.0, 40.5, 30.1, 21.0, 23.5, 37.0, 38.0, 36.5, 39.5, 20.5, 29.5, 33.5, 35.0, 26.0, 28.5, 39.5, 35.0, 31.0, 29.5, 32.5, 21.0, 36.0, 36.0, 30.5, 28.5, 32.5]

ts = pd.DataFrame(tslist)
ts.set_index(pd.date_range(start='1/1/2023', end='31/12/2023', freq='D'), inplace=True)
ts["normalized"] = (ts[0] - ts[0].mean()) / ts[0].std()
mod1 = ARIMA(ts["normalized"], order=(7,0,7)).fit()
mod2 = ARIMA(ts["normalized"], order=(1,0,1), seasonal_order=(1,0,1,7)).fit()

forecast_30 = pd.Series(mod1.predict('2024-01-01', '2024-01-30', dynamic=False))
forecast_30_sarima = pd.Series(mod2.predict('2024-01-01', '2024-01-30', dynamic=False))
ts_new = pd.DataFrame( pd.concat([ts["normalized"], forecast_30]) )
ts_new["flag"] = np.where(ts_new.index < '2024-01-01', 'truth', 'forecast')

ts_new_sarima = pd.DataFrame( forecast_30_sarima )
ts_new_sarima["flag"] = 'forecast_sarima'
```

Which gives below forecast plot zoomed in from October.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
fig = sns.lineplot(x=ts_new.index, y=ts_new[0], hue=ts_new["flag"], alpha=.7)
fig.set_xlim([ts_new.index[270], ts_new.index[394]])


fig = sns.lineplot(x=ts_new_sarima.index, y=ts_new_sarima["predicted_mean"], hue=ts_new_sarima["flag"], palette=["g"], alpha=.7)
fig.set_title("ARIMA(7,0,7) & SARIMA(1,0,1)(1,0,1) s=7 with normalized data")
```

[See forecast plot here](https://ibb.co/PY88HVX)

Comment: i cant post a comment to your answer and add an answer here. Could you look please?

Comment: Have a look at the code I provided.

Comment: I would suggest to apply limits on the top and bottom of the signal and smooth the signal a bit. Then, you have something smoother and without extreme values, which is easier to work with. I'd suggest plotting each point as a dot on the chart, draw a parallel line that goes through the middle of the dots and finds the standard deviation of each point from the parallel line. This way you can make the signal smoother until you meet a good threshold and then have all the information to reverse the effect once the forecast is complete. I haven't tried this but I think it could work in your case.

Comment: @Dimitar, I disagree on that part there. Smoothing a time series when the models used are autoregressive will follow by loss of information since the peaks and troughs are not there anymore. This can corrupt or remove fluctuations in the patterns when they are an inherent part of the hypothesis.

Comment: Oh i know about arima sarima, hw etc. I need to run a forecast on prophet. Facebook advertises it as an out-of-the-box model. There are many articles about its application. And I tried my own row. Before writing here, I tried other rows. And even sin and cos  And every time I get something that is difficult to even call a result. If you need to smooth out a row (although this is not written in the documentation) then tell me to what extent? To a straight line?

Comment: You also say I have an anomaly at the beginning. But the documentation on the main page says upload data with anomalies and even omissions!

Comment: @AndreyGulyaev, then I would say it very direct. Do not use FBProphet. It is the worst out-of-the-box model to work with because of the theoretical flaws in it. Also, your data is so volatile it is not usable for FBProphet.

Comment: @geometricfreedom true enough, measuring the extremes is often the purpose of these systems. Such example is a system which obtains the seismic actions of the earth surface over a long period of time and try to periodically predict an earthquake which is characterized as an abnormal spike in seismic actions. Applying my method would effectively make this kind of system useless as it is filtering out the very thing it is supposed to use to make the forecast. In any case, it depends on how OP wants to implement a solution. I think that the data is quite dirty to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I understood your point, but not quite like that.
I provided the data so everyone can try it.
Initially, this is the following time series:

```
tslist = [8.5, 28.0, 29.0, 40.0, 38.5, 43.0, 31.5, 29.0, 41.0, 35.5, 39.5, 31.5, 41.5, 30.0, 30.5, 36.0, 39.5, 44.0, 37.5, 42.5, 30.0, 31.0, 41.0, 38.0, 40.5, 35.0, 41.5, 36.0, 36.5, 35.0, 44.0, 42.5, 40.0, 32.5, 26.5, 30.0, 34.5, 42.5, 40.5, 43.5, 39.5, 31.0, 30.0, 38.5, 40.0, 39.0, 33.0, 44.0, 29.0, 32.0, 35.0, 46.0, 31.5, 30.5, 32.5, 29.0, 29.5, 35.5, 39.5, 40.5, 35.5, 36.5, 28.0, 28.5, 38.5, 36.5, 26.5, 25.5, 31.5, 30.0, 30.0, 35.0, 39.0, 51.5, 38.0, 42.5, 29.5, 28.0, 41.0, 35.0, 35.0, 39.5, 37.5, 24.5, 31.0, 41.0, 38.5, 28.0, 36.0, 40.5, 31.5, 30.0, 42.5, 36.0, 32.5, 37.5, 36.0, 30.0, 30.0, 36.5, 28.0, 31.0, 26.5, 38.5, 29.13, 15.5, 29.0, 38.5, 30.0, 30.0, 35.5, 31.5, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 29.0, 30.0, 30.0, 29.5, 30.0, 30.0, 36.0, 36.0, 31.5, 30.0, 24.0, 30.0, 27.0, 34.0, 31.0, 32.0, 29.0, 31.0, 37.5, 34.5, 34.5, 25.0, 35.0, 22.0, 26.0, 37.5, 34.0, 25.0, 25.0, 34.0, 31.0, 31.0, 35.5, 27.0, 29.0, 27.5, 34.0, 30.0, 28.0, 28.5, 30.0, 36.0, 31.0, 35.0, 27.5, 26.5, 33.5, 31.0, 37.0, 36.0, 28.0, 29.0, 30.0, 29.0, 30.5, 29.0, 30.0, 29.0, 25.0, 17.0, 30.0, 35.0, 30.5, 30.0, 30.0, 24.0, 21.5, 31.0, 26.0, 27.0, 32.0, 30.0, 25.0, 21.0, 33.5, 30.0, 29.5, 30.5, 29.0, 21.5, 24.0, 28.5, 23.0, 31.0, 32.5, 30.0, 29.5, 24.0, 30.0, 30.0, 29.0, 30.0, 34.0, 23.0, 24.5, 34.0, 29.0, 30.5, 27.5, 30.5, 23.0, 25.0, 29.5, 31.5, 29.0, 19.0, 25.5, 27.5, 23.5, 32.0, 21.5, 28.5, 27.5, 19.5, 27.0, 22.0, 31.0, 24.5, 31.5, 25.0, 32.0, 28.0, 30.0, 30.0, 27.0, 32.0, 28.5, 32.0, 26.5, 27.5, 30.0, 29.5, 30.0, 33.5, 37.0, 29.5, 29.0, 35.5, 36.0, 30.5, 35.5, 35.0, 28.5, 32.0, 34.0, 37.0, 31.0, 33.0, 34.5, 25.5, 28.0, 34.0, 36.0, 36.0, 36.0, 28.54, 22.5, 26.5, 37.0, 35.0, 35.5, 37.0, 35.5, 31.5, 31.5, 36.5, 36.0, 32.0, 51.33, 36.5, 32.0, 30.0, 36.0, 36.5, 37.0, 41.5, 34.5, 29.5, 28.0, 40.0, 39.5, 44.5, 35.5, 45.0, 29.5, 35.5, 41.5, 32.5, 34.5, 37.0, 51.5, 32.5, 27.0, 25.5, 40.5, 43.5, 37.5, 40.5, 28.0, 34.0, 41.5, 38.0, 38.5, 33.0, 41.0, 30.0, 33.5, 43.0, 40.5, 39.5, 42.5, 40.0, 30.5, 32.0, 33.0, 41.5, 34.5, 32.0, 42.0, 27.5, 24.0, 35.5, 34.5, 36.0, 40.5, 30.1, 21.0, 23.5, 37.0, 38.0, 36.5, 39.5, 20.5, 29.5, 33.5, 35.0, 26.0, 28.5, 39.5, 35.0, 31.0, 29.5, 32.5, 21.0, 36.0, 36.0, 30.5, 28.5, 32.5]'
```

These are bread sales in a grocery store starting from 01/01/2023 and further by day. Accordingly, on January 1, after the New Year, no one buys bread.
The second point is that this original time series is decomposed into additive components using singular spectral analysis. And the periodicity component is fed to the Prophet’s input to make a forecast.

Accordingly, this outlier at the beginning is nothing more than the minimum sales for the entire period.

The series is stationary according to DF and according to the KPSS

P.S. And look i try to make forecast for the original time series - NO RESULT... (attach jpeg)[Original TS forecast by Prophet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glwc7.jpg)